# Как я могу заставить элемент SVG двигаться по траектории?

Tags: html, svg, svg-animation

Я хочу переместить прямоугольник по траектории. Поэтому я переместил `<rect>` так, чтобы его позиция была в начале траектории. Но когда я запускаю анимацию прямоугольника, перемещение интерпретируется относительно `path`. Таким образом, прямоугольник перемещается со смещением относительно траектории движения.

Вот пример:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600px"
    height="400px">
    <defs />
    <path id="path" d="M 100 100 L 100 15 L 500 15 L 500 150" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none" />
    <g transform="translate(50,75)">
      <rect height="50" width="100" fill="#FDD34D" rx="10" stroke-width="1px" stroke="#000000">
      </rect>
      <text x="15" y="28">Click me !</text>
      <animateMotion id="move" dur="4.6s" begin="click">
        <mpath xlink:href="#path" />
      </animateMotion>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I make a SVG element to move on the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68883315/7394871) от участника  [@René Link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974186/ren%c3%a9-link).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68883315/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**С помощью JS:**

- находится центр прямоугольника; (атрибуты x,y могут быть любыми)
- выставляется позиция текста относительно прямоугольника; (изначальная позиция почти любая)
- размещается `<g>` в начальную позицию пути.

Начальная позиция пути, а также 1000 точек, распределенных по пути, находятся с помощью функции `path.getPointAtLength(distance)`. Одинаковые отрезки находятся с помощью деления `path.getTotalLength()`.

Группа (`<g>`) перемещается по точкам благодаря изменению `transform:translate()` каждые `timeInterval`.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const path = svg.querySelector('path');
const group = svg.querySelector('g');
const rect = svg.querySelector('rect');
const text = svg.querySelector('text');
   
const box = rect.getBBox();
const gcx = box.x + box.width/2;
const gcy = box.y + box.height/2;

const textBox = text.getBBox();
text.setAttribute('x', box.x + (box.width - textBox.width)/2);
text.setAttribute('y', box.y + (box.height + textBox.height*0.5)/2);

const startPoint = path.getPointAtLength(0);
group.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${startPoint.x - gcx}, ${startPoint.y - gcy})`);
group.onclick = startGroup;


function startGroup(){
    const steps = 1000;
    const timeInterval = 5;
    const points = [];

    for(let i=0; i <= steps; i++){
        points.push(path.getPointAtLength((path.getTotalLength()/steps)*i));
    }
    points.push(path.getPointAtLength(0));

    points.forEach((p,i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {moveGroup(p)}, timeInterval*i);
    })
}

function moveGroup(point){
    group.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${point.x - gcx}, ${point.y - gcy})`);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -20 800 200">
    <path id="path" d="M 100 100 L 100 15 L 500 15 L 500 150" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3"/>
    <g>
      <rect height="50" width="100" fill="#FDD34D" rx="10" stroke-width="1px" stroke="#000000"></rect>
      <text>Click me !</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Отличный, универсальный ответ. Я думаю он будет  полезен для решения [браузерных  проблем](https://caniuse.com/?search=animateMotion) с  поддержкой  `animateMotion`

Comment: Интересные методы `getPointAtStroke()`, `getPointAtFill()` и `getTotalLength()`.  А вот `isPointInStroke` и `isPointInFill` требуют создания SVGPoint через `createSVGPoint()` и назначения координат уже созданному объекту точки. Хотя на MDN указывается, что SVGPoint - depricated и в методах нужно использовать new DOMPoint(), конструктору которого можно сразу передавать координаты. Но в Хроме не пашет такое. И все равно аналогичные `CanvasContext.isPointInStroke(path,x,y)` и `CanvasContext.isPointInPath(path,x,y,fillrule)` принимают координаты без создания объектов точек.

Answer (score 2):

Основная идея состоит в том, чтобы текст и прямоугольник были центрированы вокруг точки `x = 0`, `y = 0`.

```html
<svg  viewBox="-100 -130 700 400">
    <defs />
    <path id="path" d="M 0 0 L 0 -90 L 500 -90 L 500 150" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none" />
   <g>
      <rect height="50" width="100" x="-50" y="-25" fill="#FDD34D" rx="10" stroke-width="1px" stroke="#000000"/>    
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Click me !</text>
      <animateMotion id="move" dur="4.6s" begin="click">
        <mpath xlink:href="#path" />
      </animateMotion>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68883425/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>